# Type 'FileManager.SearchPathDirectory' does not conform to protocol 'CaseIterable' in Swift

Tags: swift, enumeration

I want to use [CaseIterable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/caseiterable) on [FileManager.SearchPathDirectory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/searchpathdirectory):

```
extension FileManager.SearchPathDirectory: CaseIterable {}
```

but I get the error: "Type 'FileManager.SearchPathDirectory' does not conform to protocol 'CaseIterable'".

I suspect that RawValue is causing the problem. Next step I tried to write an enum with RawValue:

```
struct My {
    enum Number: UInt {
        case One = 1
        case Two = 2
    }
}
extension My.Number: CaseIterable {}

for item in My.Number.allCases {
    print(item)
}
```

Seems to be no problem. In the second attempt, I added the protocol stubs:

```
extension FileManager.SearchPathDirectory: CaseIterable {
    public typealias AllCases = UInt
    public static var allCases: [Self] = [.adminApplicationDirectory, .allApplicationsDirectory, .desktopDirectory]
}
```

The problem remains. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: In the documentation for CaseIterable it is mentioned that the compiler can not automatically implement a solution if the enum has `@available` attributes. At the same time going through the items in the FileManager.SearchPathDirectory one quickly see that the listed availability differs between items so my guess from this is that `@available` is used for this enum and that is why it isn’t working. I don’t know if you could implement CaseIterable for a subset of those items that are available on your platform.

Answer (score 1):

`CaseIterable` protocol only requires you to implement a static var `allCases` with a collection of all values of this type and an a associatedtype `AllCases` which is a type that can represent a collection of all values of this type.

The issue in your implementation is that your `AllCases` typealias should be a collection of `FileManager.SearchPathDirectory` which can be also written as `[Self]` instead of `UInt`:

---

```
extension FileManager.SearchPathDirectory: CaseIterable {
    public typealias AllCases = [Self]
    public static var allCases: AllCases = [.adminApplicationDirectory, .allApplicationsDirectory, .desktopDirectory]
}
```

---

```
for directory in FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.allCases {
    print(directory.rawValue)
}
```

---

This will print:

> 4
> 100
> 12